How to get device Bluetooth addresses in Python Bleak
I’m new to Bluetooth in Python so I’m not sure how to best phrase my question. The task I need to achieve, is I want to know whether a certain phone is in my vicinity through Bluetooth. I read Bleak’s docs and got the following code.
import asyncio
from bleak import BleakScanner

async def main():
    devices = await BleakScanner.discover()
    for x in devices:
        print(x)

asyncio.run(main())

This code runs without errors, but I’m not able to find which device is mine. All the names are output as None, and the device addresses do not correspond to the address shown in my phone’s settings’ About page. I’ve tried this on multiple phones and from multiple devices. My guess is that the addresses are somehow different from the ones shown in my phone’s settings.
Any pointers will be of great help. Thank you!

on what system do you run it? maybe some systems need admin privileges to get more data.

The Bluetooth specification has various features in it to make sure that untrusted parties are not able to track a device by its Bluetooth address. I wonder if you are falling foul of this? There is a good introduction at: https://novelbits.io/bluetooth-address-privacy-ble/
